# Probs. 2 (d) and 2(e) in Supplementary Exercises, Chap. 2 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: How are these maps continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Let $S^1$ denote the set of all complex numbers $z$ such that $\vert z \vert = 1$ (regarded as a subspace of the complex plane), and let the map $f \colon S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1$ be defined  by 
$$f(w \times z) \colon= wz \ \ \ \mbox{ for all } \ w \times z \in S^1 \times S^1.$$ 
Then how to determine if $f$ is continuous?

Let $\mathrm{GL}(n)$ denote the set of all $n \times n$ non-singular matrices of complex numbers regarded as a subspace of the (Euclidean) metric space $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$. Let the map $g \colon \mathrm{GL}(n) \times \mathrm{GL}(n) \to \mathrm{GL}(n)$ be defined by 
$$g(x \times y) \colon= xy \ \ \ \mbox{ for all} \ x \times y \in \mathrm{GL}(n) \times \mathrm{GL}(n).$$

Then how to determine if $g$ is continuous?

Let $p \colon \mathrm{GL}(n) \to \mathrm{GL}(n)$ be defined by 
$$p(x) \colon= x^{-1} \ \ \ \mbox{ for all } \ x \in \mathrm{GL}(n).$$

Then how to determine if $p$ is continuous?

Comment: For (1) and (2), you are looking at restrictions of polynomial functions defined on some $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.

For (3), you are considering some rational functions on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, restricted to a subset where their denominators never vanish.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, I'd appreciate if you could answer my question in more depth and detail.

Comment: What definition do you use for the topology on $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, the topology we have to use is the $T_1$ topology relative to which $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a topological group, that is, such that the maps $f \colon \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C}) \times \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C}) \mapsto \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C}) $ defined by $f(x \times y) = xy$ and $g \colon \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})  \mapsto \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C}) $ defined by $g(x) = x^{-1}$ are continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Using the metric definition.

> **Lemma 1**: Let $p:\mathbb{C}^k\to \mathbb{C}$ a polynomial map. Then, $p$ is continuous.

Let $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_k),\ \ h=(h_1,\cdots,h_k)$.

1. Notice that $\max_{i=1}^k|h_i|\le \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k|h_i|^2}=\|h\|$.
2. Let $M:=\max(1,|x_1|,\cdots,|x_k|)$. Notice that $m\le n\Rightarrow M^m\le M^n$.

$p(x_1,\cdots,x_k):=\sum_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}a_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}x_1^{d_1}\cdots x_k^{d_k}$

Hence
$$0\le|p(x_1+h_1,\cdots,x_k+h_k)-p(x_1,\cdots,x_k)|=\\=\left|\sum_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}\left(a_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}\left((x_1-h_1)^{d_1}\cdots (x_k-h_k)^{d_k}-x_1^{d_1}\cdots x_k^{d_k}\right)\right)\right|=\\=\left|\sum_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}\left(a_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}\left(\left(\sum_{j_1=0}^{d_1}{d_1\choose j_1}h_1^{j_1}x_1^{d_1-j_1}\right)\cdots \left(\sum_{j_k=0}^{d_k}{d_k\choose j_k}h_k^{j_k}x_k^{d_k-j_k}\right)-x_1^{d_1}\cdots x_k^{d_k}\right)\right)\right|=\\=\left|\sum_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}\left(a_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}\left(\left(\sum_{j_1,\cdots,j_k=0}^{d_1,\cdots, d_k}{d_1\choose j_1}h_1^{j_1}x_1^{d_1-j_1}\cdots{d_k\choose j_k}h_k^{j_k}x_k^{d_k-j_k}\right)-x_1^{d_1}\cdots x_k^{d_k}\right)\right)\right|=$$
Now, notice that the highest degree monomial of the sum in the innest parenthesys is nothing but $x_1^{d_1}\cdots x_k^{d_k}$, corresponding to $j_1=\cdots=j_k=0$. Hence, making the subtraction...
$$=\left|\sum_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}\left(a_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}\sum_{\begin{matrix}j_1,\cdots,j_k=0,\\ \exists q\ j_q>0\end{matrix}}^{d_1,\cdots, d_k}{d_1\choose j_1}h_1^{j_1}x_1^{d_1-j_1}\cdots{d_k\choose j_k}h_k^{j_k}x_k^{d_k-j_k}\right)\right|\le\\\le\sum_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}\left(|a_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}|\sum_{\begin{matrix}j_1,\cdots,j_k=0,\\ \exists q\ j_q>0\end{matrix}}^{d_1,\cdots, d_k}{d_1\choose j_1}|h_1|^{j_1}|x_1|^{d_1-j_1}\cdots{d_k\choose j_k}|h_k|^{j_k}|x_k|^{d_k-j_k}\right)\le\\\le\sum_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}\left(|a_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}|\sum_{\begin{matrix}j_1,\cdots,j_k=0,\\ \exists q\ j_q>0\end{matrix}}^{d_1,\cdots, d_k}{d_1\choose j_1}\|h\|^{j_1}M^{d_1-j_1}\cdots{d_k\choose j_k}\|h\|^{j_k}M^{d_k-j_k}\right)\le$$

In the last passage we used (1) and (2). Now we use (2) again, using that $d_i-j_i\le \deg p$

$$\le M^{k\deg p}\sum_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}\left(|a_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}|\sum_{\begin{matrix}j_1,\cdots,j_k=0,\\ \exists q\ j_q>0\end{matrix}}^{d_1,\cdots, d_k}{d_1\choose j_1}\cdots{d_k\choose j_k}\|h\|^{j_1+\cdots+j_k}\right)\le$$

Now, since we're taking the limit as $\|h\|\to 0$, we can assume that $\|h\|<1$, hence that $m\le n\Rightarrow \|h\|^n\le\|h\|^m$. But the condition "$\exists q\ j_q>0$" implies, then, that $\|h\|^{j_1+\cdots+j_k}\le\|h\|$. From which this passage...

$$\le M^{k\deg p}\sum_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}\left(|a_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}|\sum_{\begin{matrix}j_1,\cdots,j_k=0,\\ \exists q\ j_q>0\end{matrix}}^{d_1,\cdots, d_k}{d_1\choose j_1}\cdots{d_k\choose j_k}\|h\|\right)=\\=\|h\|\cdot\left(M^{k\deg p}\sum_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}\sum_{\begin{matrix}j_1,\cdots,j_k=0,\\ \exists q\ j_q>0\end{matrix}}^{d_1,\cdots, d_k}|a_{d_1,\cdots,d_k}|{d_1\choose j_1}\cdots{d_k\choose j_k}\right)\stackrel{\|h\|\to 0}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Because that monstrous (finite) sum is a positive constant that depends only on $p$.

> **Lemma 2**: The map $x\mapsto {1\over x}$ is a continuous map $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb{C}$.

Let $x,\varepsilon\in\mathbb{C},\ x\ne0$. Since we take the limit $\varepsilon\to 0$, we can assume that $|\varepsilon|<{|x|\over 2}$.

$$0\le \left|{1\over x+\varepsilon}-{1\over x}\right|=\left|-\varepsilon\over x(x+\varepsilon)\right|\le{\varepsilon\over|x|\,(|x|-|\varepsilon|)}\le{2|\varepsilon|\over|x|^2}\stackrel{\varepsilon\to 0}{\longrightarrow}0$$

> **Lemma 3** Let $f:X\to\mathbb{C}^n,\ \ f=(f_1,\cdots,f_m),\ \ X\text{ a topological space}$.
>   Then, $f$ is continuous if and only if $\forall i=1,\cdots,m\ f_i$ is continuous.

Indeed let $x\in X$, let $\delta>0,\ U_1,\cdots, U_m$ such that $\forall i,\forall y\in U_i,\ |f_i(y)-f_i(x)|<\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Then, $\forall y\in\bigcap_{i=1}^mU_i,\ \|f(x)-f(y)\|<\delta$.

> Now, your requests follow easily from restriction and from considering that $\forall A,B\in M(n,\mathbb{C})$ $$(A\cdot B)_{i,j}=\sum_kA_{i,k}B_{k,j}$$
>   And that $\forall A\in GL(n,\mathbb{C})$, $(A^{-1})_{i,j}$ is given by a rather complicated polynomial $p_{i,j}$ in the $n^2$ entries of $A$, divided by $\det(A)$, which is another polynomial in the entries of $A$, never vanishing on $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: For Lemma 1, you can just use the fact that the map $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \to x_i$ for some fixed $i$ is continuous, then induct on the (multi-)degree of the polynomial $p$. (Depending on what's assumed to be known in Munkres, you may also have to prove that addition, multiplication, etc. $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ are continuous.)